# How to assign one row of a hierarchically indexed Pandas DataFrame to another row?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign one row of a hierarchically indexed Pandas DataFrame to another row of the DataFrame. What follows is a minimal example.

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('b', 1)])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4), columns=columns)

print(data)
data.loc[0, 'a'] = data.loc[1, 'b']
print(data)
```

This fills row 0 with `NaN`s instead of the values from row 1. I noticed I can get around it by converting to an `ndarray` before assignment:

```
data.loc[0, 'a'] = np.array(data.loc[1, 'b'])
```

Presumably there's a reason for this behavior, and an idiomatic way to make the assignment?

*Edit:* modified the question after Jeff's answer made me realize I oversimplified the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [38]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=columns)

In [39]: data
Out[39]: 
          a          
          0         1
0  1.657540 -1.086500
1  0.700830  1.688279
2 -0.912225 -0.199431

In [40]: data.loc[0,'a']
Out[40]: 
0    1.65754
1   -1.08650
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [41]: data.loc[1,'a']
Out[41]: 
0    0.700830
1    1.688279
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

In your example notice that the index of the assigned element are [0,1]; These don't match the columns which are ('a',0),('a',1). So you end up effectively reindexing to elements which don't exist and hence you get `nan`.

In general its better to let pandas 'figure' out the rhs alignment (and like you are doing here, mask the lhs).

```
In [42]: data.loc[0,'a'] = data.loc[1,:]

In [43]: data
Out[43]: 
          a          
          0         1
0  0.700830  1.688279
1  0.700830  1.688279
2 -0.912225 -0.199431
```

You also could do

```
data.loc[0] = data.loc[1]
```

Here's another way:

```
In [96]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],[0,1]]))

In [97]: data
Out[97]: 
   a      b    
   0  1   0   1
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11

In [98]: data.loc[0,'a'] = data.loc[1,'b'].values

In [99]: data
Out[99]: 
   a      b    
   0  1   0   1
0  6  7   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

Pandas will always align the data, that's why this doesn't work naturally. You are deliberately NOT aligning.

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is assign a row in one pair of columns to a row in another. That is, I have a pair called 'a' and a pair called 'b', and want to assign `data.loc[0, 'a'] = data.loc[1, 'b']`. Your answer addresses my question, but in a way that doesn't solve my slightly more complicated needs.